# qemu execute mips program failed

Tags: debugging, mips, qemu

use `qemu-mipsel -cpu 34kf /usr/bin/binary` to execute a mips32 program.
program actually executed, but some errors printed and program exit.

the error is:
`Unsupported setsockopt level=65535 optname=128`

so how to debug and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setsockopt level 65535 optname 128 for MIPS is SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER. QEMU does not currently support that socket option for setsockopt; this is a bug (or missing feature, if you like) in QEMU. There is (coincidentally) a patch on the mailing list to add this support: http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/565659/   -- so it's likely that this will be fixed in the next release of QEMU (2.6).